# What plant/tree is this?

Tags: botany, species-identification, trees

Found this in a rural area next to the road last month and I wonder what is it?

[image]
[image]

From my searches I think it is a strawberry bush but I'm not sure and any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Add the site of your pictures? It might help you get a precise answer.

Comment: I took the pictures

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your pictures are a bit vague, but I think recognize *Euonymus europeus*, the **spindle tree**. So I assume the picture comes from Europe? The fruits are encapsulated in pink capsule, the fruit itself is bright orange.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euonymus